Combine fields in a nested json file into a dataframe
I have this code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, schema_of_json, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

s = '{"job_id":"123","settings":{"task":[{"taskname":"task1","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path1"}},{"taskname":"task2","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path2"}}]}}'

schema = schema_of_json(lit(s))

result_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([s], "string")
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data"))
    .select("data.job_id", explode("data.settings.task.taskname").alias("taskname"))
    )

result_df.show()

Which generates this:
+------+--------+
|job_id|taskname|
+------+--------+
|   123|   task1|
|   123|   task2|
+------+--------+

How to add the field notebook_path to the dataframe? It seems explode can't generate more than one field, and can't put two explode function in the select. I know I can create addition dataframes (job_id, notebook_path) and then join these two dataframes on job_id. Just wondering any better solution available?

You should explode the array which is task not taskname. Then you can access the fields of the exploded objects as necessary.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

s = '{"job_id":"123","settings":{"task":[{"taskname":"task1","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path1"}},{"taskname":"task2","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path2"}}]}}'

schema = F.schema_of_json(F.lit(s))
df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([s], 'string')
    .select(F.from_json(F.col('value'), schema).alias('data'))
)

cols = [
    F.col('data').getField('job_id').alias('job_id'),
    F.explode('data.settings.task').alias('task'),
]
df2 = df.select(cols)

final_cols = [
    F.col('job_id'),
    F.col('task.taskname').alias('taskname'),
    F.col('task.notebook_task.notebook_path').alias('notebook_path'),
]
result_df = df2.select(final_cols)
result_df.show(10, False)

# +------+--------+-------------+
# |job_id|taskname|notebook_path|
# +------+--------+-------------+
# |123   |task1   |path1        |
# |123   |task2   |path2        |
# +------+--------+-------------+


You just need to add one more line to the present code and change the depth in explode as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, schema_of_json, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

s = '{"job_id":"123","settings":{"task":[{"taskname":"task1","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path1"}},{"taskname":"task2","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path2"}}]}}'

schema = schema_of_json(lit(s))

result_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([s], "string")
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data"))
    .select("data.job_id", explode("data.settings.task").alias("task"))
    .select("job_id", "task.taskname", "task.notebook_task.notebook_path")
)

result_df.show()

# +------+--------+-------------+
# |job_id|taskname|notebook_path|
# +------+--------+-------------+
# |   123|   task1|        path1|
# |   123|   task2|        path2|
# +------+--------+-------------+

To make it more comprehensible why this works - we can check the schema of the task field - this way if you have more fields with a different depth - you can easily generalise this solution moving on:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, schema_of_json, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

s = '{"job_id":"123","settings":{"task":[{"taskname":"task1","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path1"}},{"taskname":"task2","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"path2"}}]}}'

schema = schema_of_json(lit(s))

result_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([s], "string")
    .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data"))
    .select("data.job_id", explode("data.settings.task").alias("task"))
    # .select("job_id", "task.taskname", "task.notebook_task.notebook_path")
)
result_df.printSchema()
result_df.show()

# root
#  |-- job_id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- task: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- notebook_task: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- notebook_path: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- taskname: string (nullable = true)

# +------+----------------+
# |job_id|            task|
# +------+----------------+
# |   123|{{path1}, task1}|
# |   123|{{path2}, task2}|
# +------+----------------+

